# WPDB->insert with special characters

Tags: wpdb

I'm having a problem with WPDB->insert inserting special characters.

I'm trying to insert a name (Jiří), the ř is being saved as ?.

The character is being able to inserted correctly into the database using `add_option`, which is strange.

Here is a version of the code which I'm trying:-

```
$memberdata = array( 'name' => 'Jiří', 'email' => 'someemail@address.com' );
add_option( 'temp_debug', $member_data['name'] ); // inserted as Jiří
$insert_into_temp=$wpdb->insert( wp_table, $member_data, array( '%s', '%s' ); // inserted as Ji?i
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The table where you insert the data with `$wpdb->insert()`, is it a custom table?

Comment: Can you show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_wp_table`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `wp_wp_email_capture_temp_members` (
     `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` tinytext CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
     `email` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
     `confirm_code` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
     `date` datetime NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ` @kovshenin

Answer (score 2):

If the same code works with `add_option()` and not with `$wpdb->insert()` in a custom table, it is probably because the collation of the custom table does not support the characters of the inserted data.

It shoulud work if you set the collation of your table to UTF-8, `utf8_general_ci` at minimum (to allow support for emojis, [WordPress uses `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` since version 4.2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kovshenin & @cybmeta above for putting me on the right lines :)

Although the tables were using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, the individual rows used `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Switching the rows to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, fixed this issue.

Thanks!