# wpdb->insert with special chars failing with collation utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

Tags: wpdb

I'm performing an `wpdb->insert()`. When a field includes a special the insert is not done and I get the error

> Error in Wordpress database for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_my_table`

If I don't use special characters the insert is done correctly.

Apparently, the column collations are correct, but something is wrong. I saw this [post answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246503/wpdb-insert-with-special-characters) but as I said my collations seem to be correct.

This is my table definition:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_my_table;

CREATE TABLE `wp_my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

And this is the insert statement:

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_my_table', 
             ['c_name'        => $_POST['c_name'],
              'creation_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]);
```

Adding `esc_sql` or `esc_html` didn't help.

Actually, error is not in the query or insert itself, but in $_POST['c_name'], because if I call with a hard coded string, the query works properly:

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_my_table', 
             ['c_name'        => '1º áá',
              'creation_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]);
```

Comment: not answering your question, but you shouldn't directly add $_POST data to the query, sanitize it first

Comment: what do you see when you do print_r($_POST['c_name']);

Comment: I see the real string content "1º A". Testing more I can see the only characters that it doesn't accept is º and ª, it accepts "á" and "ñ" etc.

Comment: Another form which is quite exact the same to this works and accepts all characters, although table definition is the same now maybe there's some kind of caché in mysql that keeps and old collation or something, but restarting mysql server didn't do anything

Comment: You could use `urlencode`, so `1º áá` will now be `1%C2%BA%20%C3%A1%C3%A1` and you should not have problems inserting that. @NabeelKhan is 1000% correct, always sanitize the data before insert, also, use `$wpdb->prepare`

Comment: on a very wild note, try enclosing $_POST['c_name'] with double quotes and see how it behaves

Comment: @NabeelKhan double quotes didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Use the sanitize field

```
sanitize_text_field($_POST['c_name']);
```

more info https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `,` in your query with `$_POST`.

Try this and it should work:

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_my_table', 
             ['c_name'        => $_POST['c_name'],
              'creation_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]);
```

Comment: Oh, that was only when writing code in Stack Overflow, not in my real code